# How do you parse a JSON request with Dispatch?

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I'm learning Scala, and attempting to understand how traits are working (specifically with the Dispatch library).

I've got something like this:

```
import dispatch._
import dispatch.liftjson._

object Foo
{
    def main(cmd: Array[String])
    {
        val http = new Http;
        val req = :/("example.com") / path ># (list ! obj);
        val res = http(req);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's complaining that ># is not registered with dispatch.Request. The trait is described within dispatch.liftjson, and it was my assumption that I should just need to import that trait (which _ should cover) for it to register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be importing from `dispatch.liftjson.Js._`.

Having a trait isn't helpful, as you're not then using it. The `JS._` import will bring all the contents of the `JS` object into your scope, including the [implicit conversion](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-6) `requestToJsonVerbs` which it has from `trait ImplicitJsonVerbs`. This method converts a standard Dispatch `Request`, which you have from `:/("example.com") / path`, to a `JsonVerbs`, which has the method `>#`.

Here's an abridged sample of how I query an API:

```
import dispatch._
import dispatch.liftjson.Js._

import net.liftweb.common.{Box, Failure, Full}
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers

case class Device(device_token: String, alias: Option[String])

val req = devicesReq / device_token as (app_token, secret)
Helpers.tryo(http(req ># (json => {
  json.extract[Device]
})))
```

As you can see, I have the correct imports (plus some for some [Lift](http://www.liftweb.net/) libraries I like), and my `Request` then 'has' a `>#` method. I give `>#` a function that matches the expected signature (`(JValue) ⇒ T`) and away we go.

In case you're wondering, I'm specifically using lift-json's ability to extract to case classes, meaning that `T` will be `Device`. However, lift-json also throws an exception if it is unable to convert the `JValue` to a `Device`, so I've wrapped my whole request with `Helper.tryo`, a Lift helper method that wraps a try-catch call, returning a `Box`. `Box` is like the standard Scala `Option` but with the addition of `Failure`, which indicates why a `Box` is empty. So, in this case I will get either a `Full[Device]` or a `Failure`. Handy!